# Может кто помочь с SVG моментом?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, svg

Пытаюсь сделать эту секцию SVG методом.
Смотрю видеоролики, читаю статьи, но все ровно ничего не получается.
Может кто объяснить полностью как сделать эту секцию, или скинуть именно нужные ролики и статьи, по которым вы поняли как делать подобные секции. 
И заранее попросил бы не кидать первые видео с ютуба(ибо их я и смотрел)
[image: SVG-секция]

Comment: если Вам вдруг будет это интересно, могу написать ответ как сделать такую svg без использования векторных редакторов

Comment: @Stranger in the Q хоть ты спрашивал не меня, но конечно пиши свой ответ. Чем больше способов решения одного вопроса, тем лучше. Плиз, не забудь прокомментировать свой код.

Comment: Это уже третий или четвертый вопрос с подобным шаблоном...

Comment: @Александр вы спросили, вам подробно ответили. Почему нет никакой реакции? Что-то  не понятно, так спрашивайте или хотя бы поблагодарите людей за потраченное время на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 9):

**Пошаговая инструкция:**

- Для получения точной привязки контуров фигур к фоновой картинке
  загружаем картинку в векторный редактор и присваиваем значения SVG в
  соответствии с габаритными размерами картинки.

  ```
  width="1330" height="880" viewBox="0 0 1330 880"
  ```

  ```html
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             width="1330" height="880" viewBox="0 0 1330 880" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb744.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </svg>
  ```
- В векторном редакторе с помощью инструмента - <kbd>Рисовать кривые Безье
  и прямые отрезки</kbd>

  наносим узловые точки по контурам красной линии и шестиугольников

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Сохраняем файл SVG, забираем из него `path` общей
  линии и  шестиугольников.
- Добавляем в каждый шестиугольник текст, который  позиционируем
  координатами `X`, `Y`

  ```
  <text class="txt1" x="355" y="400"  > STEP
    <tspan dx="0">1 </tspan></text>
  ```

  Добавляем картинку в шестиугольник с помощью `pattern`

  ```
  <pattern
    id="pattern"
    x="0px" y="-255px"
    width="341px"
    height="382px"
    patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
  >
    <image
      xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbkL.jpg"
      width="341px"
      height="382px"
    />
  </pattern>
  ```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1330 880"  >  
<defs> 
  <pattern
       id="pattern"
       x="0px" y="-255px"
       width="341px"
    height="382px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbkL.jpg"
        width="341px"
    height="382px"
       />
    </pattern>  
 <pattern
       id="pattern2"
       x="40px" y="-380px"
         width="304px"
      height="343px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZrmI.jpg"
             width="304px"
          height="343px"
       />
    </pattern>   
 
</defs>
  
 <g fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2">    
  <path id="hex_1" class="h1" d="m402.1 321 106.8 60.6v121.3l-106.8 64.6-106.8-64.6V381.7ZM731.7 381.7l104.1 60.6" />
  <path id="hex_2" class="h1" d="m731.7 381.7 104.1 60.6v125.2l-104.1 64.6-106.8-64.6V442.3Z" />
  <path id="hex_3" class="h2" fill-opacity="0.6" style="fill:url(#pattern2);" d="m1099.5 289.4 163.5 92.3V567.6L1099.5 658.5 940 567.6V381.7l159.5-92.3" /> 
  <path class="h2" fill-opacity="0.9"  style="fill:url(#pattern);" d="m508.9 503 160.8 94.9V782.4L508.9 876 349.4 782.4V597.9l159.5-94.9M835.8 199.7l104.1 62" class="s0"/>
  <path class="h1" d="m835.8 199.7 104.1 62v120l-104.1 60.6-104.1-60.6V261.7Z" class="s0"/>
</g>  
    <!-- Красная линия, показывающая прогресс-->
 <path id="progress" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"  
     d="m295.3 381.7 106.8-60.6 106.8 60.6v121.3l116 64.6 0-125.2 106.8-60.6V261.7l104.1-62 104.1  62v120l159.5-92.3 163.5 92.3v185.9l-163.5 91" >
 </path>   
   
</svg>
```

- Добавляем красные кружки с галочкой, вместо них можно добавить иконки, как на
  эскизе

  ```
  <g id="crc1">
    <circle  r="23" fill="#FC635E"/>
    <text x="-15" y="15" fill="white" font-size="36" >&#10004;</text>
  </g>
  ```

**Ниже полный пример кода, добавил анимацию общей линии**

```css
 .h1{
 fill-opacity:0.6;
  } 
 
  .h2 {
 fill-opacity:0.9;
  }
 .txt1 {
  font-size:32px;
  fill:#595959;
  text-decoration: underline;
   font-weight:500;
   } 
  .txt2 {
  font-size:20px;
  fill:#444444;
   font-weight:500;
   } 
 tspan {
 fill:#FC635E;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size:36px;
  }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1330 880"  >  
<defs> 
  <pattern
       id="pattern"
       x="0px" y="-255px"
       width="341px"
    height="382px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbkL.jpg"
        width="341px"
    height="382px"
       />
    </pattern>  
 <pattern
       id="pattern2"
       x="40px" y="-380px"
         width="304px"
      height="343px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZrmI.jpg"
             width="304px"
          height="343px"
       />
    </pattern>   
 <g id="crc1">
 <circle  r="23" fill="#FC635E" />   
    <text x="-15" y="15" fill="white" font-size="36" >&#10004;</text>
   </g>
</defs>

    
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC31J.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />    

 
  
 <g fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2">    
  <path id="hex_1" class="h1" d="m402.1 321 106.8 60.6v121.3l-106.8 64.6-106.8-64.6V381.7ZM731.7 381.7l104.1 60.6" />
  <path id="hex_2" class="h1" d="m731.7 381.7 104.1 60.6v125.2l-104.1 64.6-106.8-64.6V442.3Z" />
  <path id="hex_3" class="h2" fill-opacity="0.6" style="fill:url(#pattern2);" d="m1099.5 289.4 163.5 92.3V567.6L1099.5 658.5 940 567.6V381.7l159.5-92.3" /> 
  <path class="h2" fill-opacity="0.9"  style="fill:url(#pattern);" d="m508.9 503 160.8 94.9V782.4L508.9 876 349.4 782.4V597.9l159.5-94.9M835.8 199.7l104.1 62" class="s0"/>
  <path class="h1" d="m835.8 199.7 104.1 62v120l-104.1 60.6-104.1-60.6V261.7Z" class="s0"/>
</g>  

 <path id="progress" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"  stroke-dashoffset="1975"    stroke-dasharray="1975"
     d="m295.3 381.7 106.8-60.6 106.8 60.6v121.3l116 64.6 0-125.2 106.8-60.6V261.7l104.1-62 104.1  62v120l159.5-92.3 163.5 92.3v185.9l-163.5 91" >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="10s" values="1975;0" fill="freeze"/> 
  </path>   
  
 <text class="txt1" x="355" y="400"  > STEP
     <tspan dx="0">1 </tspan></text>   
     <text class="txt2" x="312" y="450"> Разработка проекта</text>
    <text class="txt2" x="300" y="490"> Согласование проекта </text>
 
   <text class="txt1" x="425" y="725"  > STEP 
     <tspan dx="0">2 </tspan></text>  
      <text class="txt1" x="680" y="450"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">3 </tspan></text>   
      <text class="txt2" x="670" y="500"> Нулевой цикл</text>
      <text class="txt2" x="640" y="540"> Возведение коробки </text>
    
    
   <text class="txt1" x="790" y="280"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">4 </tspan></text>   
         <text class="txt2" x="750" y="330"> Монтажные работы</text>
      <text class="txt2" x="750" y="370"> Отделочные работы </text>
         
     <text class="txt1" x="1150" y="430"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">5 </tspan></text>       
   <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="300" y="380" /> 
    <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="628" y="440" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="735" y="255" /> 
     <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="945" y="385" />
     <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="1100" y="655" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Зачем пиксели в размерах?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно и так и так :) на работоспособность не влияет. Пишу на всякий случай пиксели, так как где-то, когда-то у меня не сработало. Перестраховка конечно :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот на [toster](https://toster.ru/q/653458) вчера задали вопрос о том как делать такие shape я там ответил и даже записал видео как это делается: [Как делать Shape](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrx9i8vfzcp2tk0/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20shape.mp4?dl=0)

На выходе получаем вот это :

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #F3F5F5;
}

.item {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 85 300 215" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <defs>
     <style>
      .path{fill: #fff; stroke:#999; stroke-width: 0.5;}
      .parent{stroke:tomato; stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-width:3; fill: none;}
      .circle{fill: tomato;}
      .text{font-size: 8px; font-weight: 600; fill: #fff; font-family: fontawesome;}
        .descr{font-family: sans-serif; fill: #999; font-size: 10px;}
        .descr1{font-family: sans-serif; fill: #999; font-size: 6px;}
        .d2{fill: tomato;}
        .line{stroke-width:1; stroke: #999;}
     </style>
      <clipPath id="cp">
            <path  d="m25.958501 210.22236 47.401997-28.3337 48.602062 28.64167-0.60003 56.97535-47.10199 29.25761-48.302039-29.25761z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
   <image xlink:href="https://cache3.youla.io/files/images/360_360/5c/a4/5ca4dfcf65bcf114356a4c36.jpg" x="20" y="170" width="130" height="130" transform="translate(1,-1)" preserveAspectRatio="none" clip-path="url(#cp)"/>
  
    <path class="path" d="m10.957868 143.3918 31.501331-17.86256 30.60129 17.86258 0.300012 38.49684-30.9013 18.78648-31.50133-19.40242z"/>
  
    <path class="path" d="m107.56195 164.64207 32.40136-19.40242 30.90131 18.17052 0.30002 38.18888-32.40138 18.78648-31.20131-19.09445z"/>
    <path class="path" d="m170.86462 163.41017-30.90131-18.17052v-38.49686l30.6013-18.786458 30.6013 18.786458-0.60004 37.26497z"/>
    <path class="path" d="m248.56791 229.00882-48.00204-27.71774v-57.28332l47.70202-27.40977 47.40199 28.64166-0.90003 55.43549z"/>


   <path class="parent" d="m10.957868 143.3918 31.501331-17.86256 30.60129 17.86258 0.300009 38.49684 34.201452 19.40242v-36.64901l32.40136-19.40242v-38.49686l30.6013-18.786458 30.6013 18.786458-0.60004 37.26497 47.70202-27.40977 47.40199 28.64166-0.90003 55.43549-46.20194 28.33368"/>

    <g><title>1</title><circle class="circle" cx="9" cy="142.62187" r="7" /></g>
    <g><title>2</title><circle class="circle" cx="108" cy="162.17827" r="7" /></g>
    <g><title>3</title><circle class="circle" cx="139.81332" cy="106.43483" r="7" /></g>
    <g><title>4</title><circle class="circle" cx="200.71588" cy="142.77585" r="7" /></g>
    <g><title>5</title><circle class="circle" cx="246"  cy="228" r="7" /></g>

    <text class="text" x="4" y="145.5"></text> <!-- font-awesome -->
    <text class="text" x="104" y="165"></text> <!-- font-awesome -->
    <text class="text" x="135.5" y="109.5"></text> <!-- font-awesome -->
    <text class="text" x="196.5" y="146"></text> <!-- font-awesome -->
    <text class="text" x="241.5" y="231"></text> <!-- font-awesome -->
  
    <g>
      <text x="25" y="150" class="descr">
        <tspan class="d1">STEP</tspan>
        <tspan class="d2" x="54">1</tspan>
      </text>
      <line x1="25" x2="60" y1="154" y2="154" class="line"/>
        <text x="25" y="150" class="descr1">
          <tspan x="25" y="165">lorem ipsum</tspan>
          <tspan x="25" y="172.5">sit dollar it</tspan>
          <tspan x="25" y="180">ammed circular</tspan>
       </text>
    </g>
  
    <g transform="translate(96,20)">
      <text x="25" y="150" class="descr">
        <tspan class="d1">STEP</tspan>
        <tspan class="d2" x="54">2</tspan>
      </text>
      <line x1="25" x2="60" y1="154" y2="154" class="line"/>
        <text x="25" y="150" class="descr1">
          <tspan x="25" y="165">lorem ipsum</tspan>
          <tspan x="25" y="172.5">sit dollar it</tspan>
          <tspan x="25" y="180">ammed circular</tspan>
       </text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(126,-35)">
      <text x="25" y="150" class="descr">
        <tspan class="d1">STEP</tspan>
        <tspan class="d2" x="54">3</tspan>
      </text>
      <line x1="25" x2="60" y1="154" y2="154" class="line"/>
        <text x="25" y="150" class="descr1">
          <tspan x="25" y="165">lorem ipsum</tspan>
          <tspan x="25" y="172.5">sit dollar it</tspan>
          <tspan x="25" y="180">ammed circular</tspan>
       </text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(210,0)">
      <text x="15" y="150" class="descr">
        <tspan class="d1">STEP</tspan>
        <tspan class="d2" x="54">4</tspan>
      </text>
      <line x1="5" x2="70" y1="154" y2="154" class="line"/>
        <text x="25" y="150" class="descr1">
          <tspan x="5" y="165">lorem ipsum</tspan>
          <tspan x="5" y="172.8">sit dollar it</tspan>
          <tspan x="5" y="180">ammed circular</tspan>
          <tspan x="5" y="188">ammed circular bon ittem</tspan>
       </text>
    </g>
    

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: нормально получилось. Шестиугольник с картинкой подвинь влево и вверх, чтобы убрать зазор с другим шестиугольником (STEP1) (+)

Comment: нижнего бордюра не видно у `STEP1`